# Realtime updates internal server error on Heroku using Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, heroku, real-time, koala

I'm trying to generate a realtime updates subscription using the Koala gem deployed on Heroku. However, when I run the following:

> @updates = Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates.new(:app_id => APP_ID, :secret => APP_SECRET)
> @updates.subscribe("user", "feed", CALLBACK_URL, VERIFY_TOKEN)

at the heroku console, I get:

```
 !   Internal server error
```

However, when I check my Heroku logs, I don't see a 500 error. In fact, everything seems hunky-dori:

> **heroku[router]:** GET blah-blah-760.heroku.com/facebook_updates/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5951ms status=200 bytes=10
>
> **heroku[nginx]:** 66.220.149.250 - - [05/Oct/2011:11:55:11 -0700] "GET /facebook_updates/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1234567890&hub.verify_token=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.0" 200 10 "-" "facebookplatform/1.0 (+http://developers.facebook.com)" blah-blah-760.heroku.com

When I paste the GET request into the browser, it echoes the hub.challenge parameter correctly.

My controller is as follows:

```
class FacebookUpdatesController < ApplicationController

  layout nil

  def index #this method responds to the Facebook GET 
    logger.info "about to meet challenge"
    render :text => Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates.meet_challenge(params, VERIFY_TOKEN)
  end

  def create #this method responds to POST messages
    logger.info params
  end

end
```

My routes are configured as follows:

```
resources :facebook_updates, :only => [:create, :index]
```

I feel like I'm really close. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also tried using an :app_access_token for the @updates = Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates.new(:app_id => APP_ID, :app_access_token => APP_TOKEN) instantiation with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't handle the both requests at the same time, if you run the `@updates.subscribe("user", "feed", CALLBACK_URL, VERIFY_TOKEN)` at a local console it will work.

Comment: Thanks a million, pjaspers, that was it. I was under the impression that I need to make the subscription from the production environment. The local console approach was key.

Comment: And what if I want to make the subscription dynamically?